# In GIT, how can I know on which branch a specific commit was initially made ? And/or which commits were initially made on a specific branch?

Tags: git, commit, branch

I came out with the following trick which kind of works, but I'm sure there must be an easier way to do this.
For each commit, I actually take the first line of the 'git branch --contains ...' command.

```
while read v t
do 
    echo -e "$v\t\c"
    git branch -r --contains $v | head -1 | tr -d "\n"
    echo -e "\t$t"
    v=""
    t=""
done
```

```
    0d0098b4e         origin/2021.10.EM1    XXX-2360 : Function2: XXX 4.1 Upgrade  ....
    476d60fa5         origin/2021.10.EM1    XXX-2362 : Function2: XXX 4.1 Upgrade  ....
    49455ce5d         origin/2021.10.EM1    XXX-2362 : Function2: XXX 4.1 Upgrade  ....
    47b1f1817         origin/2021.10.EM1    XXX-2362 : Function2: XXX 4.1 Upgrade  ....
    e10f005ef         origin/2021.10.EM1    XXX-2360 : Function2: XXX 4.1 Upgrade  ....
    7317613b5         origin/2021.10.EM1    XXX-2353: Revert change from wrong JIRA ....
    16b41ce0c         origin/2021.10.EM1    XXX-2353 : Function2: XXX 4.1 Upgrade  ....
    4756fe099         origin/2021.10.EM1    XXX-2353 : Function2: XXX 4.1 Upgrade  ....
    8c557c520         origin/2021.04.OoC    XXX-2339 : Function2: XXX 4.1 Upgrade  ....
    6054b16a1         origin/2021.04.OoC    XXX-2339 : Function2: XXX 4.1 Upgrade  ....
    ad9d66057         origin/2021.04.OoC    XXX-2339 : Function2: XXX 4.1 Upgrade  ....
    b19ad447e         origin/2021.04.OoC    XXX-2083 : reset calendar mechanism to previous behaviour ....
    c1c03a83c         origin/2021.04.OoC    XXX-2083 : Update default value for PROD to false to keep old behaviour ....
    33c034f37         origin/2021.09.Minor  XXX-1901 YYY-817 : Added the Business calendars back ....
    acbbfaf4a         origin/2021.09.Minor  XXX-1901 YYY-817 : Removal of business calendars ....
    1f5d74216         origin/2021.04.OoC    XXX-2292 : Function2: XXX 4.1 Upgrade  ....
    117f0ca7c         origin/2021.04.OoC    XXX-2083 : Update default value for PROD to true to keep old behaviour ....
    dffc5810e         origin/2021.04.OoC    XXX-2322 : Function2: XXX 4.1 Upgrade  ....
    a6590add6         origin/2021.04.OoC    XXX-2322 : Function2: XXX 4.1 Upgrade  ....
```

Also, how could I easily get the list of commits which were originally made, for example, on branch '2021.04.OoC' ?

Comment: ok so this is difficult to answer, because it depends on your git workflow and branching strategy. Generally git-adherents will advocate for short-lived branches, and that means that if you merge and delete a feature branch, you won't be able to track that a line was modified on that branch. you will however be able to see the commits that were merged up, which commits have that commit in their lineage, and which branches have that commit. git log is helpful, as is git log graph, but i think the thing youre most looking for is tags. I'd probably write a script to auto-make a tag when I merge.

Answer (score 0):

It is actually pretty easy, with

```
git log <branch>
```

Comment: After a merge you wouldn't be able to tell on which branch the commit was originally made, which I'm pretty sure is the point of the question.

Comment: Indeed, that was the point.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible.

Branches in Git are just pointers at specific revisions (commits). As you add more commits and push them, the branch pointer is moving locally and remotely. Then, after a branch is deleted, it is gone. Even if it not deleted, the branch pointer may move in a way that makes the information unavailable.

You can infer, to a reasonable degree, where a commit came from, when using a sound Git branching strategy and by looking at commit messages of merge commits. These messages usually contain the names of both branches that were merged. If you’re using multi-branch merging (octopus merge), the guessing gets a lot harder though.

---

If you’re not using a branching strategy, you should seriously consider it. If you’re relying on branch names for… well, anything, really, you should probably stop it. It’s unreliable at best.

Comment: There are circumstances where long-lived branches are both viable and even wise, but those are few and far between, and as you say, short-lived branches that come and go are considered the norm in the git community. I use long lived branches for Salesforce, but it really is a very different animal than the vast majority of coded projects. our UAT branch for instance contains all the code that has reached the UAT stage in our process. the key difference is that SF exists as the org and deployments are deltas, rather than replacing the deployed app with a new version of it.